Computing homology groups for a torus and a ball identified by a circle with Mayer-Vietoris sequence
The question is:

Let $X = S^1 \times S^1$ be a torus and let $A = S^1 \times \{x_0\}$ be a circle in $X$. Let $B = \{(x, y, 0) \in \mathbb R^3 | x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subset S^2 = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 | x^2 + y^2+z^3 = 1\}$ be a circle in $S^2$. Let $Y$ be the identification space from $X \cup S^2$ by identifying the circle $A$ with the circle $B$. Compute the homology groups for $Y$ of any orders.

My working:

Consider the M-V sequence:
$$\cdots \to \tilde H_k(X \cap S^2) \overset{\Phi}{\to} \tilde H_k(X) \oplus \tilde H_k(S^2)  \overset{\Psi}{\to} \tilde H_k(Y) \overset{\partial}{\to} \tilde H_{k-1}(X \cap S^2) \overset{\Phi}{\to} \cdots$$
By noting that $\tilde H_k(X \cap S^2) = \mathbb Z$ for $k=1$ and $0$ otherwise, $\tilde H_k(X) \oplus \tilde H_k(S^2) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ for $k=1,2$ and $0$ otherwise, we have $\tilde H_k(Y) = 0$ for any $k \geq 3$. The sequence reduces to
$$0 \overset{\Phi_2}{\to} \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \overset{\Psi_2}{\to} \tilde H_2(Y) \overset{\partial_2}{\to} \mathbb Z \overset{\Phi_1}{\to} \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \overset{\Psi_1}{\to} \tilde H_1(Y) \overset{\partial_1}{\to} 0,$$
where $\Phi_1$ sends $1$ to $(1,1)$, hence $\tilde H_1(Y) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z /\text{image}(\Phi_1) = \mathbb Z$. Note that $\text{ker} \Phi_1 = \text{image} \partial_2 = 0$, we have $\partial_2 =0 $. Hence $\text{ker} \partial_2  = \tilde H_2(Y) = \text{image}\Psi_2$. Therefore $\Psi_2$ is surjective, and it is injective due to exactness. We have $\tilde H_2(Y) = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$.


To sum up, the homology groups are: $H_0(Y)  = H_2(Y)= \mathbb Z$, $H_1(Y)  = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$, and $H_k(Y) = 0$ for $k \geq 2$.

Would you like to help me check my answer? Thanks!

Generally I would think of $\Phi_1 (1)=(1,0)$, however, since $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is free I think $\Phi_1 (1)=(1,1)$ holds true in an appropriate basis. This doesn't change the answer at all as $\Phi_1$ is still injective, so this looks good!

@user_not_found Got it! I missed the point that for $k=1$, $\tilde H_1(S^2) = 0$, the contribution of $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ only comes from the torus. Thank you very much for your help!
